# How do I fix the Vuetify installation npm error E404

Tags: npm, error-handling, vuetify.js

Please help me to resolve this issue, I have no idea how to fix this... I already uninstalled and re-installed Vue, Vue/cli and npm (also updated these to the latest version)

After this I created a basic vue app with these commands in the terminal

```
vue create cms
```

This was successful

then I cd into the folder

```
cd cms
```

Now I run the dev server:

```
npm run serve
```

It started up and everything seemed fine...the default vue app was working...along with the router that was set up in the creation process

After this, I tried to install the veutify plugin with:

```
vue add veutify
```

But I receive this in the terminal:

PS C:\Users\Wollie\Desktop\cms> vue add veutify
 WARN  There are uncommited changes in the current repository, it's recommended to commit or stash them first.
? Still proceed? Yes

�  Installing vue-cli-plugin-veutify...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-veutify - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'vue-cli-plugin-veutify@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wollie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-11T19_35_59_890Z-debug.log

ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error vue-cli-plugin-veutify -D

Here is the image

How do I fix this so that:
 1. veutify is installed correctly 
 2. open the dev server so that the veutify demo page loads by default.

I am a total noob starting out so this will help me a lot Thanks

[Screen Shot of actual error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzpSF.jpg)

Answer (score 14):

Spelling mistake!!!

You typed *vue add **veu**tify* It should be *vue add **vue**tify*

Comment: i had the same exact issue lol. thanks for saving me from a few hours of frustration

Comment: that's quite a big LOL